# SIGTERM not intercepted by the handler in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js

I have an extremely simlple shutdown hook in my Node app, however, I do not see it being invoked in debug mode, neither I see the log.

`process.on('SIGTERM', () => { console.log('SIGTERM signal received.'); });`

I am sending a signal with: `kill -s SIGTERM <pid>`

After that in console I see:

```
SIGTERM signal received.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 143
npm ERR! pdf-generation-service@0.0.0 start: `nodemon dist/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 143
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pdf-generation-service@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2023-02-28T16_24_28_081Z-debug.log
```

Below you can find the entire debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/19.6.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v19.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~prestart: pdf-generation-service@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: pdf-generation-service@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/code/pdf-generation-service/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/user/.cargo/bin
9 verbose lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/user/code/pdf-generation-service/app
10 silly lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'nodemon dist/index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 143  signal: null
12 info lifecycle pdf-generation-service@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: pdf-generation-service@0.0.0 start: `nodemon dist/index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 143
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:512:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
14 verbose pkgid pdf-generation-service@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/user/code/pdf-generation-service/app
16 verbose Darwin 22.3.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/19.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v19.6.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.18
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 143
22 error pdf-generation-service@0.0.0 start: `nodemon dist/index.js`
22 error Exit status 143
23 error Failed at the pdf-generation-service@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 143, true ]
```

I am trying to understand what can be off here?

I tried nuking my cache and removing node modules, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re seeing exit code 143 because `kill` is sending `SIGKILL` to the `npm run` process as well as `node`. From [Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/ROG3H81R/why-does-sigterm-handling-not-work-correctly-in-nodejs-with-npm):

> In order to do proper signal handling in node, you'll want to not run as a child of npm. When you `npm run foo`, your node process is started as a child of npm, but npm won't handle signals like a normal process manager might. When we send the `SIGTERM` signal, we send it to every process. If you're executing your app with npm run, that means npm also receives the signals. What it decides to do with them afterwards is up to npm, and in the case of `SIGTERM` on Linux, that is to immediately kill any children (including your app) and to exit with a code of 143.

The fix is to run `node index.js` instead of `npm run`, so your `node` process is top-level and can handle signals directly.

Comment: Hmm, if you're seeing `terminated` that means that the `SIGKILL` is going through, which likely means that your `process.on` is never called and the handler is never installed. Make sure that you're calling `process.on` as close to the top of your `index.js` as possible, _not_ after any other blocking calls (like `app.listen()` for an Express server, for example). Feel free to update your question with the full `index.js` to help debug if nothing obvious jumps out.